# Installation and reinstal

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a problem with diablo 3 cd key. Beforehand, I had to install diablo on my computer. And not accidentally uninstall the game a few months later. I tried to install it on my laptop but the cd key can only be used once. Are there any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8):

The CD key is tied to a battle net account. If you log into the same battle net account you will not have any issues. There should be nothing stopping you from installing the game.

If you are having issues with the physical disc install, you can log into your [battle.net](http://us.battle.net/en/) account and download the installer from the Blizzard website directly.